# using cargo maven plugin to deploy spring project to remote server

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm using eclipse for developing. I tried to deploy to remote server using cargo plugin, but I got an error. I'm using EC2 as my server, with tomcat 8.I used `cargo:deploy` when I tried to run or debug.

here is my error

`Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.3:deploy (default-cli) on project travelplanner:`
`Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.3:deploy failed: Failed to create deployable with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.TomcatWAR for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x]], deployable type [war]).` 
`InvocationTargetException: Failed to parse Tomcat WAR file in [my workingspace\travelplanner-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war]: Failed to find file [my workingspace\travelplanner-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war]: my workingspace\travelplanner-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]`

and here is my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <container>
                <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                <type>remote</type>
            </container>
            <configuration>
                <type>runtime</type>
                <properties>
                    <cargo.hostname>myIPaddress</cargo.hostname>
                    <cargo.remote.username>myId</cargo.remote.username>
                    <cargo.remote.password>myPassword</cargo.remote.password>
                    <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://myIpAddress:8080/manager/text
                    </cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.rosem</groupId>
                        <artifactId>travelplanner</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location where the war file can be found. Check the location tag under deployable tag in plugin configuration.